# Iterating properly through groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

There is a specific problem with iterating properly through a pandas groupby object and I do not yet understand the underlying dynamics good enough to solve my problem.

Below, there is a short sample code to simulate my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import random

rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['foo','bar','baz']*3, 
               'B': [400,800,800,1200,400,1200,800,400,1200],
               'C': rand.randn(9), 
               'D': rand.randint(0, 20, 9)})
df.head(9)
```

Now I need to iterate through that dataframe grouped by the two columns 'A' and 'B' to group first by 'bar', 'baz' and 'foo' and afterwards by 400, 800 and 1200 and select then values from columns 'C' and 'D' for the plots - below my attempt for the selection:

```
for k1, gp in df.groupby(['A']):
    print '1st key =' + str(k1)
    for k2, gp in df.groupby(['B']):
        print '2nd key =' + str(k2)
        print gp[['C','D']]
```

That produces the output

```
1st key =bar
2nd key =400
      C   D
0  1.624345  14
4  0.865408  17
7 -0.761207   9
2nd key =800
      C   D
1 -0.611756  18
2 -0.528172   4
6  1.744812  13
2nd key =1200
      C  D
3 -1.072969  9
5 -2.301539  0
8  0.319039  9
1st key =baz
2nd key =400
      C   D
0  1.624345  14
4  0.865408  17
7 -0.761207   9
2nd key =800
      C   D
1 -0.611756  18
2 -0.528172   4
6  1.744812  13
```

What is really close to what I need but, the values for C and D are listed from the whole data. He doesn't grab for example only the values for 'A' = 'bar' **and** 'B' = 800 but all values for 'B' = 800  regardless of the name in column 'A'.

What I would like to create is instead is something like:

```
1st key =bar
2nd key =400
      C   D
4  0.865408  17
7 -0.761207   9
2nd key =800
      C   D
1 -0.611756  18
1st key =baz
2nd key =800
      C   D
2 -0.528172   4
2nd key =1200
      C   D
5 -2.301539
8  0.319039
```

I hope, this is possible in a groupby object since it seems to be a clean and flexible solution. I am also open to a loop with logical conditions, but if possible, I would like to solve it the groupby fashion. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `groupby`s A values, then, for each such value, `groupby`s again *the entire dataframe* by B, so that's why you're getting too many combinations.

To do what you want, your double loop should `groupby` the B values only on the result of the first `groupby`:

```
for k1, gp1 in df.groupby(df.A):
    print '1st key', k1
    for k2, gp2 in gp1.groupby(gp1.B):
        print '2nd key', k2
        print gp2
```

(Note the difference in the 3rd line), which outputs

```
1st key bar
2nd key 400
     A    B         C   D
4  bar  400  0.865408  17
7  bar  400 -0.761207   9
2nd key 800
     A    B         C   D
1  bar  800 -0.611756  18
1st key baz
2nd key 800
     A    B         C  D
2  baz  800 -0.528172  4
2nd key 1200
     A     B         C  D
5  baz  1200 -2.301539  0
8  baz  1200  0.319039  9
1st key foo
2nd key 400
     A    B         C   D
0  foo  400  1.624345  14
2nd key 800
     A    B         C   D
6  foo  800  1.744812  13
2nd key 1200
     A     B         C  D
3  foo  1200 -1.072969  9
```

Comment: Tuple unpacking in `for` is still there in Python 3.  Only tuple-unpacking in function argument signatures was removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts and answers so far. But I do not yet see a way to select the data from columns 'C' and 'D' properly as shown above in the last box - how could one use the keys k[0] and k[1] to achieve this result?

Comment: See now this version.

Comment: Hello. Great: adopted to the "real" dataframe where I have to apply this loop, it worked out perfectly! To groupby w.r.t the first groupby object in that way is something I should have figured out myself. Apologize for my ignorance ;-)